# html/javascript: Replace top of dropdown menu/Show active filter?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, drop-down-menu, filter

For a Wordpress page, I am using filter buttons to filter the display of posts depending on their respective categories. The filter buttons work via a small javascript which turns on and off the display of the posts depending on the post-category the button is linked to.

Now, I would like to make these buttons accessible through a dropdown menu, which always shows which filter button is active. Putting them into a dropdown menu was no problem. However, with the next step I need some help: I would like the dropdown menu to always show the active filter button which the user has clicked on, at the top of the menu itself (i.e. instead of the menu's original title which is displayed when the page is loaded, before any buttons inside the menu have been clicked). How might that be possible?

Here's the html of the filter buttons inside the dropdown menu as well as the javascript which enables the filter buttons to filter the post-categories:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown Menu Title</button>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <button class="btn" id="category-filter1">  Filter 1    </button>
        <button class="btn" id="category-filter2">  Filter 2    </button>
        <button class="btn" id="category-filter3">  Filter 3    </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javscript:

```
<script>
    var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {

      if (this.id == 'all') {
        $('.projects > .post').fadeIn(300);
      } else {
        var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(300);
        $('.projects > .post').not($el).fadeOut(300);
      }
      $btns.removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Run your script at document.ready to set active class to your desired menu item. And before doing that remove active class from other menu items

Comment: drop-down-menu, is that a javascript file that I can find , without needing Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this..

You must get the text from the active list and add it to the title div or button.

```
var textx = $(this).text(); 
$('.dropbtn').text(textx);
```

Example of whole code : https://jsfiddle.net/eh4chb48/

Only if i got ypur question right! :) ;)